# Why short calling form not working for table in Lua 5.3?

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

Lua 5.3

This doesn't work,  why ? Why short calling form not working for tables ?

```
t = { "a", "b", "c" }
s = t:concat()
```

this works ...

```
s = table.concat(t)
```

Comment: Because `s = t:concat()` is the same as `s = t.concat(t)`.  See why that would be incorrect?

Comment: Because tables don't have a default metatable to the `table` library table the way strings do.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` library exports its functions to the metatable that's shared by all strings. That's why you can use `str:upper()` just like `string.upper(str)`.

That's not the case for the `table` library. You have to set the metatable manually. For example, this works:

```
local t = { "a", "b", "c" }
t.__index = table
setmetatable(t, t)
local s = t:concat()
print(s)  -- abc
```

Comment: That was the conclusion I was gettting too,  but why the system does not already bind the package Table to all table by default,  a var seem to be a Variant (and union of few type) so for a string you also probably get a pointer to the String Package, then the s:find... got redirect ...  if table  was link the same way the short  t:concat, will work fine,  it can also be extent to   t:xxx  if __metatable is defined the interpreter can search in the metatable of the object ...  t in that context is no longer a table but more of a prototype ( prototype programming style) ...

Comment: @voidptr All strings share the same metatable. Making all tables share the same metatable is generally a bad idea. It's common for a table to have its own custom metatable.

Comment: I don't think so ^^^^...  maybe 99% of the time tables in scripts might  be use has kind of vectors or table(aka Smalltalk dictionary) and deal with commons data,  so having a more complete single metatable can be pretty useful...  on the other part, if you want to used a table for other reason or functionality, you still can remove the link to the standard table and put you own, ex for emulation class or prototype base languages or to just have useful muck objects ...  It is just me anyways :o)